# Bold font size is not changed for \setmainfont

Tags: xetex, fontspec, fontsize

I wanted to typeset a document with Times New Roman 18pt size (using xelatex). MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[SizeFeatures={Size=18}]{Times New Roman}
\newcommand\test{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Header 1}: \test
    \item \textbf{Header 2}: \test
    \item \textbf{Header 3}: \test
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

I get this:

[image]

Unfortunately, the bold headers were not changed. How to fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the `SizeFeatures` independently for the bold and italic variants.

**Aside:** You don't need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` with `xelatex`. It's ignored with utf8 based engines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}[%
  UprightFeatures={SizeFeatures={Size=18}},
  ItalicFeatures={SizeFeatures={Size=18}},
  BoldFeatures={SizeFeatures={Size=18}},
  BoldItalicFeatures={SizeFeatures={Size=18}},
]
\newcommand\test{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \emph{Header 1}: \test
    \item \textbf{Header 2}: \test
    \item \textbf{\emph{Header 3}}: \test
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]